# Which book authored recently covers at least the same material as _Differential Geometry of Three Dimensions_ by C. E. Weatherburn?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, notation, book-recommendation

I was just a short while ago reading Chapter 1 of the book *Differential Geometry of Three Dimensions* by C. E. Weatherburn, volume 1, and found that there were certain terms being used by the author that were a bit confusing or at least not in conformity with the terms used in more recent books (on calculus).

For example, Weatherburn refers to "consecutive points" on a curve, a term which does not make much mathematical sense (to me at least) in view of the fact that between any two real numbers (and hence between any two points on a continuous curve) there are infinitely many others and thus there is no such thing as two "consecutive" real numbers.

Accordingly, I would like to have a book on differential geometry that covers at least the same material as covered by the above-mentioned book by Weatherburn but does so in a more rigorous and detailed manner.

Comment: I have never encountered this book, despite having worked in differential geometry for close to 50 years. I'm not sure it was ever remotely a "classic reference." Why did you pick it? It brags about the introduction of vector methods. Well, we all use vector methods (since the latter half of the preceding century). I don't have access to the table of contents, but you should probably start with any one of the standard modern texts. My own free text (linked in my profile) should get you started, and then doCarmo's standard undergraduate text will add some topics I do not cover.

Comment: One of my favorite undergraduate DG books is "Differential Geometry and Its Applications", by John Oprea. It has friendly explanations, lots and lots of beautiful pictures, gives you some idea on how to use some softwares (I think that he uses Mathematica), and the last chapter gives you an introduction to higher dimensional geometry.

Comment: @Ivo: No, it used to be Maple (unless he's changed it). Unfortunately, Maple has (had?) no interface between vectors (linear algebra) and multivariable calculus, so it leads to the antithesis of vector-oriented mathematics.

Comment: Oops. Just checked here, it's Maple (it has been a long time since I took a look at it), yes. It's the book by Gray which uses Mathematica, I just remembered. Anyhow, my tip to OP is to check several books, see how each of them treat a given topic, and create your own understanding from it (I never stuck to a single book myself).